# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::make() isn't working on my local machine

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

So for some reason on my local machine make() method isn't working this is what i'm trying to do

```
   public function adunit($position)
{
    $default_adunits = $this->defaultAdunits();

    $adunit = Cache::remember("programs:{$this->program_id}:adunit:{$position}", 5, function() use ($position){
        $pivot = DB::table('program_video_adunit')
            ->where('program_id', $this->program_id)
            ->where('position', $position)
            ->first();

        return (! empty($pivot)) ? VideoAdunit::find($pivot->video_adunit_id) : null;
    });

    return $adunit ?? VideoAdunit::make(['link' => $default_adunits[$position], 'position' => $position]);
}
```

Comment: The code you posted here doesn't help anybody help you. And which line exactly is Laravel complaining about?

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa on VideoAdunit::make(['link' => $default_adunits[$position], 'position' => $position]);

Comment: What version of Laravel 4 are you using?

Comment: its laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create new `VideoAdunit`. The correct method to use is `create`. `make` is not defined in Laravel QueryBuilder to the best of my knowledge.